# Vector field on n-manifold whose sum of indexes is equal to Euler charasteristic

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

For 2-manifolds and 3-manifolds such a **tangent** field (whose singular points indexes sum to manifold's Euler chracteristic) construction can be done visually. For example, for triangulated 2-manifold it's shown in the following picture

[image]

Is there a universal formula for the field in higher dimentions?

Comment: The theorem holds for all dimensions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem

Comment: Exactly the one I'm proving :) We have these numbers on each of highest-dim simplexes of triangulation (deg of the field - whose existence we are going to validate - on their boundaries), prove that their sum is field-independent. And now I want to construct a field with this sum (euler number) equal to Euler characteristic.

Comment: This is an amazing theorem which will leave you stunned for a couple of days or more. It holds for ALL vector fields with isolated zeros on a compact orientable manifold.

With many surprisingly strong implications, such as: A vector with no zeros exists iff the Euler Char is zero. Thus, no such vector field on $S^2$, but one on Torus.

Answer (score 1):

There is a such formula for manifolds. A good refernece is Thurston's [Three-Dimensional Geometry and Topology](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/6086.html), which he did this explicitly by coloring the vertices for the surfaces. There is no spoiler here, as Thurston only gave hints, not complete solution to the problem. Enjoy!

Comment: Where in this book he addresses this question? I can't find anything related in contents and index there.

Comment: @Stan: The first chapter covered this in depth. Did you read at all?

Comment: The whole book? :) I took a look at contents and index. Now I looked through the first chapter and it seems to me that only case of 2-manifolds is covered. There is an excercise to carry out the proof for any dimension, But that is exactly my question. The last step in my proof to construct such a field, but use an exact formula for it. May be I miss something in this book (which seems to be good). I would be thankful if you could be more precise.

Comment: @Stan: The proof really generalizes to $n$-dimension without much difficulty. You replace triangles with $n$-simplexes to triangulate the manifold, and the vector field is similar. The hard part is to show homotopy invariance, counting the index, etc. And Thurston did it very, very carefully. There is not much I can say other than "learning from the master". I am not even qualified to be his disciple.

Comment: It generalizes of course. The only problem with building this good vector field as  a last step which is quite visualizable in 2- and 3-case (and in proofs it's just drawn). In upper dimesions I wanted to have a concrete formula for the vector field.

Comment: @Stan: Do it iteratively. Assume that you have a formula for $n-1$ simplex, then extend the vector field radically using a barycentric subdivision to all the $n-1$ dimensional faces using the formula already established, etc. If you normalize the simplex to be $\sum x_{i}\le 1$, you should be able to write out a point's coordinate using the barycenter as the origin.